# Spring security enabled and no longer serves default login page or handles requests made to "myserver/login"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I have been working through a demo on Spring Security and have simultaneously been trying to add login credentials to my existing app. Everything was going fine until there was a longer section in which the demo had me create a custom authentication filter, and upon booting up, the login page had disappeared and was returning a 404 from requests sent to `myserver/login`. From the last time it was working, I created the following security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()));
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

I have read a bunch of questions and thought there was something going on with the custom authentication filter and my not having specified the login page, and I've since changed this configuration to:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()));
    }
```

In debugging, I can see that the http configuration is being run. Nothing in the custom auth filter is being reached at this point outside of the constructor, but in case it matters, the filter code is as follows:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,
                password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String access_token = createToken(user, request, response, 10);
        String refresh_token = createToken(user, request, response, 60);
        Map<String, String> tokens = createTokenMap(access_token, refresh_token);
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), tokens);
    }

    private String createToken(User user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, int minutes) {
        //Poor practice acknowledged... only exposed for this demo application
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
        return JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (minutes * 60 * 1000)))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("roles",
                        user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);
    }

    private Map<String, String> createTokenMap(String access_token, String refresh_token) {
        Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
        tokens.put("access_token", access_token);
        tokens.put("refresh_token", refresh_token);
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

I have the following dependencies for security/web in my gradle build:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.3.0.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.18.1'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
```

Since I ran this tutorial by integrating it with my existing app that uses a React front-end, I think the conflict may come from there already being routing in place, but that doesn't make too much sense to me, as the login page was being served up until I implemented the custom authentication filter.

At this point, I've tried reverting a bunch of code to attempt to get back to the point that I have a login page, but nothing has worked. Is there anything I can add to offer the default spring functionality back at `myserver/login`? I'd really like to play with requests for tokens/etc. and ultimately explore basic registration for this app.

Let me know if any other code may be needed. Thanks!

Comment: Hard to make a suggestion. Can you try adding ".permitAll()" after ".formLogin().loginPage("/login")"?

So it will be ".formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()"

Comment: When you use the `loginPage` dsl, you are telling Spring Security that you have a custom login page. If you want to use the default login page, you can omit `loginPage`, like this: `.formLogin().and()...`

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these made a difference. The app still has nothing protected by a login. Additionally, when I began with Spring Security, it gave me a default password, and it no longer does that. Although the configuration annotation does have Spring run through the http config, it feels like security is entirely disabled.

Comment: You are specifying `authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()`, which means all requests are permitted without authentication.  Maybe you should try using `authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()`

Comment: first of all, you are setting `.formLogin().loginPage("/login")` which means, that spring boot expects you, to provide a login page at that location. Are you serving something there? Second, can you please also supply your debug logs. Third, passing username and password as query parameters, is extremely dangerous, also, filters are usually not used as a point for login. filters are used to veryfy people that supply tokens or session cookies.

Comment: TBH the tutorial you are following seems to be very bad, and i would instead recommend you following some of springs own tutorials. There are A LOT of bad spring security tutorials out there.

Comment: Changing `authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()` to `authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll()` got a login page! I omitted specifying the page as I don't yet have a custom one, but this worked, @httPants. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the warning, @Toerktumlare. There have been a number of things in this tutorial where something is added temporarily as a means of showing some functionality and removed later with an explanation as to why it isn't how we want to set things up. I'm fairly clueless and it may not be a great tutorial, but I'm not sure if the current config can be judged that way. I'll look into Spring's own materials!

Comment: As a follow-up, I'm now in a situation where I tried to log in one time with a username that doesn't match any in the database, and now all requests to the base URL of the server redirect to `/login` and return a 404. I am in over my head, but my guess from this config is that I was authenticated even on bad credentials and was given a 60-minute token, so now it's no longer trying to authenticate me? Does this sound plausible?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()` to `authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll()` got a login page! I omitted specifying the page as I don't yet have a custom one, but this configuration did lead me to a point where I can mess with login credentials, which was my original question, so I'm posting this as the answer. Follow-up question in the comments.